How Do I Add a Menu Item to a Popup Menu in a SharePoint List
I have a requirement to add a menu item that will process an email URL and paste it into the column of a column in a list.
In the screen shot below, you can see a popup menu appears when I click the three dots in a description item. I want to add an additional item to the popup and then place a returned value into the current description column.
I am not sure how to start this.  Can you please point me in the right direction.
Thank you.


You can click the edit button above and choose to add your menu item using "Customize with Power Apps".

